# How to fix (Mongoose : Error 11000) when Passed in Data is completely new and different in collectionName.create(newData,

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So, I'm writing an application where a user can create a'trip' which is basically a set of locations they wish to travel to at a particular time and date and the price they're charging for every point they wish to travel to.

The only problem is that when I do MongoDBCollectionName.create(data, (err,newTrip)=>{...}), I get the same error (after there's 1 document in the collection) :

ERROR reported while creating a trip from the driver... { MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: hitchhiqe.trips index: username_1 dup key: { : null }

Now, what I don't understand is where index : username_1 came from because none of the fields in my mongo document contains username_1.

Really appreciate any help.

I tried the following:

1. Set sparse to true. But that didn't do anything.
2. I'm currently storing data in a global variable (i know it's a bad programming practice, but it's necessary for this project because i'm holding data onto multiple post routes before finally saving it).
3. I thought the global variable might've caused some issues (even though console.log(global.data) prints out whole data every-time. So, I stored the new data into a local variable within the Post Route. But it still produces Error: 11000
4. I'm using res.locals to collect data from current user. So, in the global variable (which is object of objects (see code below)), I'm passing the value for some keys as req.user.username or req.user.birthday. I don't think this could be the problem as I already set the value for such fields in MongoDB as {unique : false}
5. I went almost every single post on Stackoverflow and YouTube on Error : 11000 but no matter what I try (I implemented sparsing from one of stackoverflow posts), I still get the same error.
6. I used mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; But that didn't do anything (someone in stackoverflow recommended it).
7. I'm REALLY in need of help. I've tried debugging it for days but to no success. My head hurts. THANK You SO MUCH for helping!

HERE's MY mongoDB Schema - Trip - :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var TripSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // Destination and price for each point
    Trip : 
    {
        // Where is the user leaving from (no price, obviously)
        from : 
        {
            destination : String
        },

        //First via point (if applicable)
        A : 
            {
                destination : {type : String, sparse : true},
                price : {type : Number, sparse : true}
            },
        //Second via point (if applicable)
        B : 
            {
                destination : {type : String, sparse : true},
                price : {type : Number, sparse : true}
            },    
        // Final Destination (REQUIRED)
        C : 
            {
                destination : {type: String, sparse : false},
                price : {type : Number, sparse : false}
            }
    },   
    // Leaving date, time, and the number of seats available
    Logistics : 
        {
            date : String, //When the user is leaving
            time : String, // Time the user is leaving
            ejsTimePosted : String, //Time ejs will start hiding the event
            seats : Number, // Number of seats available
            totalDuration : Number,
            totalDistance : Number,
            ejsTimeDeleted : Number //Time to send user an email about trip
        },

    dateCreated : String, //date this ride was made available

    // Information about the user who posted/requested a ride 
    Driver : {
        note : String,
        name : {type : String, unique : false},
        email : {type : String, unique : false},
        phone    : String,
        profilePicture : String,
        sex : String,
        carImages : String,
        car        : String,
        university : String,
        graduationYear : String
    }
});

TripSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Trip", TripSchema);
```

---

This is where I get data from a user (this is way before I save anything into the db) :

Here's the GLOBAL Variable, TripInformation :

```
global.TripInformation = {
  Trip :
  {
     from : 
     {
      destination : req.body.from.split(",").slice(-3).toString().trim()
     },
     A : 
     {
      destination : first_via_point.trim(),
      price       : req.body.first_via_point_price
     },
     B : 
     {
     destination : second_via_point.trim(),
     price       : req.body.second_via_point_price
     },
     C : 
     {
     destination : req.body.to.split(",").slice(-3).toString().trim(),
     price       : req.body.final_destination_price
     },
     },
     Logistics : 
     {
     date : req.body.leaving_date,
     time : req.body.leaving_time,
     ejsTimePosted : toTimestamp(req.body.leaving_date+", "+ req.body.leaving_time),
     seats : req.body.seats_available,
     totalDistance : parseFloat(tD/1609.344).toFixed(1),
     totalDuration : parseFloat(parseFloat(tS/3600).toFixed(1)),
     ejsTimeDeleted : departureT + tS
     },
    dateCreated : moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'),
      Driver : {
       note : req.body.note,
       name : req.user.name,
       email : req.user.username,
       phone    : req.user.phone,
       profilePicture : req.user.profilePicture,
      sex : req.user.sex,
       carImages : req.user.Driver.carImages,
        car       : req.user.Driver.car,
       university : req.user.university,
       graduationYear : req.user.graduationYear
   }
};
```

AS YOU CAN SEE, I stored it in a global variable.

NOTE : toTimeStamp() is a function that converts human readable time into a timestamp (I defined it as a global function)

### Now, this is in a different ROUTE.

After this, I'm sending user to a 'Preview' route where they can preview the  data they inserted. If they confirm, they are taken to CONFIRMATION route where I store in their data into Trip (name of my collection) Document.

Here's the code :

```
router.post("/confirm-route", function(req, res){

    Trip.create(global.TripInformation, function(err, newTrip){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("ERROR reported while creating a trip from the driver...", err);
            return res.redirect("/drive/new");
        }
        else
        {
             console.log(newTrip, 'SUCCESS!!!');

            return res.redirect("/marketplace");
        }

    });
})
```

Here's the actual error message :

---

```
Everytime there's at least 1 document in the collection, the following error is produced : 

ERROR reported while creating a trip from the driver... { MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: hitchhiqe.trips index: username_1 dup key: { : null }
    at Function.create (C:\Users\qasim\Desktop\Exigence\HItchhiqe\source code\src\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:43:12)
    at toError (C:\Users\qasim\Desktop\Exigence\HItchhiqe\source code\src\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:149:22)
    at coll.s.topology.insert (C:\Users\qasim\Desktop\Exigence\HItchhiqe\source code\src\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\collection_ops.js:859:39)
    at C:\Users\qasim\Desktop\Exigence\HItchhiqe\source code\src\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:397:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  driver: true,
  name: 'MongoError',
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  errmsg:
   'E11000 duplicate key error collection: hitchhiqe.trips index: username_1 dup key: { : null }',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

---

NOW, the only problem is that the data is completely different, literally everything. Also, I have no idea where username_1 comes from in dup key. I tried refactoring my code but I keep getting the same results. I have used similar techniques in my previous projects (except for global variables because I didn't need it there) but it works there perfectly.

---

P.s, this is my first post on stackoverflow. So, if this question seems like a lot, my apologies. I'll definitely make the next question much shorter, haha.

I really hope you can help me as I've tried almost everything and don't want to give up when I'm so close being done. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: this usually occurs when you have a null value stored in particular key, and your code tries to assign null to some other record. try to find username = null in your record and remove it

Comment: OK. so, I did this in my mongo terminal :

> db.trips.dropIndex('username_1')
RESULT : { "nIndexesWas" : 18, "ok" : 1 }

1. Could you explain what that result means?
2. Does that mean I'd no longer get such an error (ERROR : 11000)?
3. Are there ways to prevent the above error?

THANKS!!!

Comment: mehta-rohan, But I never had Username field in my db. SO how did I even get such an error for username : null?

Comment: run `db.trip.getIndexes()` you will find all the indexes associated with your collection. The above error came due to duplicate value in unique index.

Comment: Perfect. It worked! I just remembered that I had initially set up my schema with a username field and changed it later. Guess i hadn't removed the index already associated in the db even though i removed it using drop().

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in my case with a key named "**emp_organizationId**" and when I check the database collection indexes, there I found those indexes are store, removing them, solved my problem or as said by **@Qasim Wani,** simply drop them by using the command

`db.trips.dropIndex('key_name')`

[image]